# Update specific section of data in mongoDB using Node.js

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

I am looking to modify one particular object within a larger JSON object using mongoDB and Node.js. Something like this:

```
{
    "first": {
        "value": "v1",
        "status": "s1"
    },
    "second": {
        "value": "v2",
        "status": "s2"
    },
    "third": {
        "value": "v3",
        "status": "s3"
    }
}
```

and I want to say replace only the middle value with something like this:

```
{
    "second": {
        "value": "v2.2",
        "status": "s2.2"
    }
}
```

At first I thought something like this:

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db 
var db = new Db('database', new Server('localhost', 27017), {safe:true});
var second = { "second": {
                  "value": "v2.2",
                  "status": "s2.2" }
             }
db.open(function(err, db){
    db.collection('collection').update({}, second, {'upsert':true}, function(err, updated){ 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`$set`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set) operator to update a specific field like `second`:

```
var second = { "second": {
    "value": "v2.2",
    "status": "s2.2"
}};
db.collection('collection').update({}, {$set: second}, function(err, updated){
```